# base_url doesn't work in external js and css file

Tags: php, javascript, css, codeigniter

I was trying to call "`base_url()`" inside of an external `.js` file.
my '`test.js`' file path is "`js/test.js`".

**my `test.js` code was:**

```
    function download(s){
        var w=window.open('<?php base_url(); ?>home/download?f='+s+'.ogg','Download','height=100,width=100');
    }
```

And I linked that file(my js file is working fine when trying simple JavaScript codes) :

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But that always said that the access was denied and asked for server permission.

I tried '`site_url()`' too, even I tried just an echo "`hello`" in '`download`' function but those didn't work. But when I add that code inside of `header.php` view file like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function download(s){
        var w=window.open('<?php base_url(); ?>home/download?f='+s+'.ogg','Download','height=100,width=100');
    }
</script>
```

Then that worked.

And in case of external CSS when I write:

```
background:url('<?php base_url(); ?>images/side.png');
```

That doesn't work. But if I write:

```
background:url('../images/side.png');
```

Then that works.

So how can I call  "`base_url()`" inside of external `.js` file and `.css` file ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is that <script> block being called from within a PHP file? PHP code only gets executed from known php files. Ie. *.php or *.inc files (given your installation is stock)

Comment: if I use javascript block in a php file only then base_url works.

Comment: you could make js/css files into php w/header of Content-type: text/javascript to make it a css/js

Comment: Yeah, or you can cheat it and just put it in a php file, but thats a tad bit risky.

Comment: got it.so I will put those particular code blocks in my header.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call base_url() in a javascript / css file.

You need to put a relative path in these js/css files. 
PHP scripts aren't aren't run unless they're in a .php file.

Comment: so would I have to use that particular css or js code in header.php file ?

Comment: Yea thats exactly how i'd get around your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Using This Solution Just Keep in mind that you have to put the Script tag before the external js script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var baseURL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

Now Use baseURL variable in that external js.